# Error in elasticsearch: Invalid snapshot name snapshot with the same name already in-progress

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have a problem.
I want to store an index that is in elasticsearch. I created a new repository for this and this repository does not have any snapshots. But when I ran the code blog below, it returned me the error message "Invalid snapshot name snapshot with the same name already in-progress ". How can I fix this problem?

**I created a new repository with the following code block:**

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup_repository
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "compress" : "true",
    "location": "C:/backups/backup_my_index"
  }
}
```

**just to be sure i used the code block below and the query returned me this result:**

```
GET /_snapshot/backup_repository/_status

result:
{
  "snapshots" : [ ]
}
```

**I wanted to make a backup with the following code block:**

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup_repository/my_snapshot?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "my_index",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "metadata": {
    "taken_by": "busra duygu",
    "taken_because": "backup for my_index"
  }
}
```

**Error :**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_snapshot_name_exception",
        "reason" : "[backup_repository:my_snapshot] Invalid snapshot name [my_snapshot], snapshot with the same name is already in-progress"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "invalid_snapshot_name_exception",
    "reason" : "[backup_repository:my_snapshot] Invalid snapshot name [my_snapshot], snapshot with the same name is already in-progress"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I would be very happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if there is a snapshot that already exist with this name

```
GET /_snapshot/backup_repository/_all
```

You will also get the state of it `(SUCCESS/FAILED,...)`

Answer (score 0):

@ExploZe
As you said i ran this query and it returned me the following result.

**Query:**

```
GET /_snapshot/backup_repository/_all
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "snapshots" : [
    {
      "snapshot" : "my_snapshot",
      "uuid" : "4Sv055VjQDSZvpBqSvCxpg",
      "version_id" : 7100199,
      "version" : "7.10.1",
      "indices" : [
        "my_index"
      ],
      "data_streams" : [ ],
      "include_global_state" : false,
      "metadata" : {
        "taken_by" : "busra duygu",
        "taken_because" : "backup for my_index"
      },
      "state" : "IN_PROGRESS",
      "start_time" : "2021-09-09T06:22:16.414Z",
      "start_time_in_millis" : 1631168536414,
      "end_time" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end_time_in_millis" : 0,
      "duration_in_millis" : 0,
      "failures" : [ ],
      "shards" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "failed" : 0,
        "successful" : 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.